# Java Servlets Large number of Requests and Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

In one of my interview I was asked how servlets work and I told them for every request,servlet container creates a thread upon which he asked again then if we take a popular site like facebook which gets a huge number of requests and if we allocate a thread to each of this request then it wouldnt be a good approach,how do they handle such many request.I thought of thread pool but i do not know whether this is the approach.Someone please explain how such many of requests are handled in servlet container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches here that complete each other:

1. yes, limit the number of threads to a fixed number and pre-create them into a pool - thus preventing the costly process of re-creating them every time. I think Apache's HTTP server works this way.

   2. You can always throw more machines at the problem. Large sites always use clusters of web-servers, thus balancing the load.